# Salesforce REST API query - URL limit

Tags: java, rest, get, salesforce, soql

I am currently using the *Salesforce REST API* to fetch the records from Salesforce by passing the query via the query parameter in the GET request. However, this particular implementation returns an error when the url query parameter character count is more than `16000`. Is there a way to get it to accept around 1,00,000 chars in the url?

Comment: Could you clarify that value at the end? Did you mean `100,000` chars?

Comment: Yes mate , sorry for the format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like you're just hitting the limits imposed by Salesforce:

> SOSL search query strings
>
> Maximum length of SearchQuery string
>
> If the `SearchQuery` string is longer than 10,000 characters, no result rows are returned. If `SearchQuery` is longer than 4,000 characters, any logical operators are removed. For example, the `AND` operator in a statement with a `SearchQuery` that’s 4,001 characters will default to the `OR` operator, which could return more results than expected.
>
> Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_soslsoql.htm

I don't know the Salesforce API at all, but I have two suggestions (especially if no one else answers your question):

1. Investigate a `POST`/`PUT` based query option in the Salesforce REST API. I think I read something about being able to format a query in JSON and then submitting that instead (but I could be wrong). **Edit: I looked a little more, and I didn't see anything immediately that said this was a possibility**.
2. Use a less specific, and therefore smaller, query. If you're making this URL call from an application that you have control over (e.g., shell script, Java application, etc.), massage the data at that level and return a smaller subset of that data. If you're worried about getting too much data back at once, that shouldn't be a problem. It sounds like they limit the amount they send back per request and send a URL at the end of each response to the next page of results.

Comment: I explored at the option of getting smaller queries mate , but the issue is I need a larger query because each time i dynamically append a condition into that query .. So its not possible for me to have smaller query

Comment: @AmNovice ah ok. Maybe you could describe exactly how this query is generated and give an example of the query? Maybe myself or someone else could help you there?